# What is the difference between passing data through constructor and arguments of DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a simple `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
class MyBottomSheetDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    companion object {

        private const val SOME_KEY = "some_key"

        fun newInstance(something: Boolean): MyBottomSheetDialog {
            return MyBottomSheetDialog().apply {
                arguments = bundleOf(SOME_KEY to something)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Which I then display with:

```
MyBottomSheetDialog.newInstance(false).show(childFragmentManager, "my_dialog")
```

What is the advantage of this typical approach to just using a constructor parameter and displaying the dialog like this:

```
class MyBottomSheetDialog(private val something: Boolean) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    ...
    ...
}

MyBottomSheetDialog(false).show(childFragmentManager, "my_dialog")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple thing is if your class undergoes for a configuration changes then system looks for default constructor to recreate the class i.e without parameters at that you will get Exception.

Comment: Oh...I completely forgot about the fact that it's still a fragment that will be recreated haha. Missed that completely, thanks.